# How to reverse the axis in ILNumerics

Tags: graph, plot, reverse, figure, ilnumerics

I want to reverse the Y axis in ILLinePlot from top to bottom (from descending become ascending). My result is like this:
[image]
here is the code:

```
            scene.Add(new ILPlotCube {
              new ILLinePlot(ILMath.tosingle(ZDistance["1,0;:"]),
                             markerStyle: MarkerStyle.Dot)
            });
```

How to reverse the Y axis become like this figure?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the plot cube around the X axis by 180°:

```
ilPanel1.Scene.Add(new ILPlotCube {
    Children = {
        new ILLinePlot(ILSpecialData.sincos1Df(200,1)[":;0"].T)
    },
    Rotation = Matrix4.Rotation(new Vector3(1,0,0), ILMath.pif)
});
```

[image: ILNumerics line plot with reversed Y axis]

You may want to further configure the plots axes.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I lost my label on Y axis. Do you know how to fix this?